# Ошибка в регулярных выражениях либо в выводе WinForms

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++-cli

Решил задачу, описанную в коментарии, через регулярки в WinForms. Но что бы я не вводил, выводит что номер верный. В чём ошибка? Помогите, пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   #pragma endregion
        /*Основная часть автомобильного государственного регистрационного номера состоит из 6 символов: трех букв и трех цифр.
        Сначала идет буква, затем 3 цифры и еще 2 буквы заканчивают запись.
        В качестве цифр могут использоваться любые цифры от 0 до 9, а в качестве букв только прописные буквы,
        обозначения которых присутствуют как в английском, так и в русском алфавите, т.е. только следующие символы: A, B, C, E, H, K, M, O, P, T, X, Y.
        Например, «P204BT» - правильный номер, а «X182Yx» и «ABC216» - нет.
        Определить, является ли введенный номер верным.*/

    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    private:
        System::Boolean^ beng(System::String^ nom)
        {
            return Regex::Match(nom, "^[ABCEHKMOPTXY]\\d{3}[ABCEHKMOPTXY]{2}$")->Success;
        }

        System::Boolean^ brus(System::String^ nom)
        {
            return Regex::Match(nom, "^[АВСЕНКМОРТХУ]\\d{3}[АВСЕНКМОРТХУ]{2}$")->Success;
        }

        System::Boolean^ buk(System::String^ nom)
        {
            nom = nom->Trim();

            return (beng(nom) || brus(nom));
        }

        System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
        {
            if (buk(textBox1->Text))
            {
                String^ k = "Верный";
                textBox2->Text = System::Convert::ToString(k);
            }
            else
            {
                String^ k = "Неверный";
                textBox2->Text = System::Convert::ToString(k);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Регулярки действуют одинаково в приложениях любого типа: WinForms, консольные, веб-сервисы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй заменить `System::Boolean^` на `bool` или `System::Boolean`.

Comment: Да, так и сделал, спасибо, помогло

Comment: @llatibro, в таком случае прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Точно, забыл, извините)